# Problem with python xlwings as the code runs forever

Tags: python, xlwings

I am trying to autofit excel sheet in python using **xlwings** and the code is running forever

```
import xlwings as xw

filename = r"C:/Users/morgan/Downloads/tmp.xlsx"

with xw.App(visible=False) as app:
    wb = xw.Book(filename)
    for ws in wb.sheets:
        ws.autofit(axis="columns")
    wb.save(filename)
    app.quit()
```

**also tried**

```
wb.close() # rather app.quit()
```

Comment: Add a `print(ws.name)` inthe loop

Comment: Wow. Thanks. that worked.. but why it won't work without print statement. That is really weird.